# C#, Nuget Can I management Dependency Framework level assemblies?

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

I'm Nuget packaging with CreateNewNugetPackageWithEachBuild.

Nuget auto installs dependencies another Nuget packages. It works.

But this is not work in Framework libraries like the `System.Drawing` namespace, `UIAutomationTypes` assemblies etc.

So when I install my Nuget package, after install that -> and goto "add reference" menu and add framework assemblies manually (`System.Security` or something, not yet added another DLLs when create project time).

Can I make Nuget pakcages to auto-include the .Net Framework level assemblies  when install it?

Answer (score 0):

Make .nuspec file in project folder (be with .csproj file) and define frameworkAssemblies in nuspec file and build it to makes nupkg contains framework level assemblies and auto include when install it